# Visual Studio 2019 16.7.3

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I update my visual studio 2019 version 16.7.2 To 16.7.3 today.
when debugging Blazor Client assembly Windows blue Screen appears. (DPC_WATCHDOG_Violation)
I debug the same project yesterday with no problem for hundreds of times with no problem.

os :Windows 10 Enterprise.
inel core i7 6700k
16GB Ram